# Extending and then Sorting Underscore js

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure it out how can I extend and then sort the items by the created extension variable.

```
if(score === 'Overall Score'){

         // let midtermSort = _.sortBy(overAll, 'overall_score');
         _.each(students, function(elem) {
              _.extend(elem, {overall_score : (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2});
              _.sortBy(elem, 'overall_score');
               console.log(elem.firstname + " " + elem.overall_score);
         });
       }
```

As you can see on my code, I iterate to the students and then extend a new column w/c is overall_score. So right now I need to sort the items via overall_score.

Here's what I got:

[image]

As you can see the overall score does not SORT them properly. Anything i was doing wrong? Please help.

**UPDATE Side Note:** 
I tried to mixed it up with each function and it works but it was a long process. Any idea how to refactor it a little bit?

```
  if(score === 'Overall Score'){

            let overAllScore = _.each(students, function(elem) {
             _.extend(elem, {overall_score : (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2});
           });

            let sorted = _.sortBy(overAllScore, 'overall_score');
            _.each(sorted, function(elem) {
               console.log(elem.firstname + " " + elem.final_score);
            });
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want, assuming of course that you wanted them listed from lowest to highest overall score. Note that I've indented the code for readability:

```js
var score = 'Overall Score';

var students = [
  {
    firstname: 'Frank',
    midterm_score: 80,
    final_score: 80
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Julie',
    midterm_score: 50,
    final_score: 65
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Eddie',
    midterm_score: 100,
    final_score: 73
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Bill',
    midterm_score: 60,
    final_score: 67
  }
];

if (score === 'Overall Score') {
  _.each(
    _.sortBy(
      _.map(
        students,
        function(elem) {
          return _.extend(elem, {overall_score : (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2});
        }
      ),
      'overall_score'
    ),
    function(elem) {
      console.log(elem.firstname + " " + elem.overall_score);
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`_.sortBy`, according to the documentation, **returns a sorted copy of the Array**. This is unlike the standard `Array.sort()`.

You need to keep this value:

```
elem = _.sortBy(elem, ...)
```

Or, if you want to keep the entire dataset, use `map` instead of `each`:

```
students = _.map(students, function(elem) {
    ...
    return _.sortBy(elem, ...)
})
```

Comment: _.map(students, function(elem) {
              _.extend(elem, {overall_score : (elem.midterm_score + elem.final_score) / 2});
              _.sortBy(elem, 'overall_score');
               console.log(elem.firstname + " " + elem.overall_score);
         });

Comment: would that code works? I checked it but it doesnt show up.